# Three.js pin object to right side of another

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, position, group

I have a cube and a sphere, both created into three.js. Now the cube moves around and rotates, while the sphere is stationary. **I want the sphere to always be on the right side of the cube, regardless of it's position or rotation. So if the cube rotates, the sphere should move because the position of the right side changes.** I can do it by creating a group:

```js
let objects = new THREE.Group();
objects.add(cube);
objects.add(sphere);
scene.add(objects);
```

This works fine, but is it possible to do this *without a group*? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using a group? If you set the rotation with `objects.rotation.set(x, y, z)` then the cube and its adjacent sphere will rotate together.

Comment: @Marquizzo. For more context, I'm trying to create an FPS game. I'm trying to combine the camera with the gun loaded. The problem is, I can't group them because I am using `PointerLockControls.js`

Comment: _Technically_, you can add children to a `Mesh` (because it inherits from `Object3D`), so you _could_ do: `cube.add( sphere );` This serves the same purpose, where the transformation of the cube is passed down to the sphere, making its positioning local to the cube. _Personally_, I'd stick with the group.

Comment: I also just skimmed the `PointerLockControl` code. Based on the properties used, it looks like you could pass in a `Group` instead of a `Camera` and have it work correctly. You would just need to ensure the camera is facing the correct direction within the `Group`.